# ionic2 slider is not working with *ngFor - angular2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

**Screen prints of Problem!!**

When we click over **Skip** button - the **Login** page opened!

[image]

The **Login** Page!

Now, again click over the **Home** icon the Slider page will opened!!

[image]

**Problem:**

***- Slider stopped working! Only one image displaying and it doesn't worked, when trying to slide..!***

[image]

**Here is code:**

```js
    slides = [
        {
          title: "Welcome to the Platform!",
          description: "The <b>Ionic Component Documentation</b> showcases a number of useful components that are included out of the box with Ionic.",
          image: "img/ica-slidebox-img-1.png",
        },
        {
          title: "What is platform?",
          description: "<b>Ionic Framework</b> is an open source SDK that enables developers to build high quality mobile apps with web technologies like HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.",
          image: "img/ica-slidebox-img-2.png",
        },
        {
          title: "What isPlatform?",
          description: "The <b>Ionic Platform</b> is a cloud platform for managing and scaling Ionic apps with integrated services like push notifications, native builds, user auth, and live updating.",
          image: "img/ica-slidebox-img-3.png",
        }
    ];
```

```html
<ion-content class="home-slider-page">
 <ion-slides pager>
  <ion-slide *ngFor="let slide of slides">
   <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons end>
     <button block (click)="goToCategoryPage()">
      Skip
     </button>
    </ion-buttons>
   </ion-toolbar>
   <img [src]="slide.image" class="slide-image"/>
   <h2 class="slide-title" [innerHTML]="slide.title"></h2>
   <p [innerHTML]="slide.description"></p>
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>
   <ion-toolbar>
   </ion-toolbar>
   <img src="img/ica-slidebox-img-4.png" class="slide-image"/>
   <h2 class="slide-title">More Products?</h2>
   <button large clear (click)="goToCategoryPage()">
    Continue
    <ion-icon name="arrow-forward"></ion-icon>
   </button>
  </ion-slide>
 </ion-slides>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Create a demo of the problem, otherwise there are too much unclear.

Comment: Thanks for taking interest! 
Here is the link of demo - https://i.diawi.com/vVs2tn

Comment: i have same problem, did you solve that?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a delay can fix this bug.

In your Typescript file

```js
 export class SliderPage {
   loaded = false;
   constructor() {

   }
   ionViewLoaded() {
     setTimeout(() => {
       this.loaded = true;
     }, 400);
   }
 }
```

View

```
<ion-slides *ngIf="loaded&&slides.length>0" pager>
  <ion-slide *ngFor="let slide of slides">
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-buttons end>
        <button block (click)="goToCategoryPage()">
          Skip
        </button>
      </ion-buttons>
    </ion-toolbar>
    <img [src]="slide.image" class="slide-image" />
    <h2 class="slide-title" [innerHTML]="slide.title"></h2>
    <p [innerHTML]="slide.description"></p>
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>
    <ion-toolbar>
    </ion-toolbar>
    <img src="img/ica-slidebox-img-4.png" class="slide-image" />
    <h2 class="slide-title">More Products?</h2>
    <button large clear (click)="goToCategoryPage()">
      Continue
      <ion-icon name="arrow-forward"></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if I understand correct but I don't think it's a problem of ngFor because first time is working good. Only when you open second time the page it's not working.

Also in your last screenshot the slider seems to have only one page.. I think it's a problem with your page, maybe you remove from slides variable, or you make a wrong initialization (on a page events you clean the slides variable).

Comment: I didn't clean the slides variable. Suppose If I do so, then that should not displayed the first image! Isn't it ..?

Comment: please add in the ionViewLoaded event another slide in slides to see if you have 2 slides when you come from login

Comment: There's no problem with ngFor, there's a problem with ion-slides that doesn't support ngFor properly.
Also, this is in no way a solution to the problem at hand.

Comment: what means ion-slides doesn't support ngFor properly? I use the following code and works good: <ion-card-content>
           <ion-slides [options]="{pager:true}">
               <ion-slide *ngFor="let photo of articleImages">
                   <img [src]="photo.Url">
               </ion-slide>
           </ion-slides>
        </ion-card-content>